# Cannot seem to use javac in command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac

so I installed the JDK and JRE a long time ago and have been a heavy developer with the netbeans IDE but I figured I should learn the basics of command prompt launching of java programs.

I am currently running windows 8 on a 64 bit machine and cannot seem to get the "javac" command to run properly on command prompt

I created a file that contained my java file I wanted to compile "TheClass.java" and I am able to use the 'cd' command to set the command prompt pointer at the correct file.

From there when I type "javac TheClass.java"

I get the response " 'javac' not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file"

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You should add the path to the javac executable to either the user or system path, or you could use the full path to the javac executable when you compile.

Comment: thanks that seemed to fix it!